# Is this "the winding number"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, winding-number

> Note that $p:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}:z\mapsto e^z$ is a covering map.
>
> Let $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ be a closed curve.
>
> Let $\gamma$ be any lift of $\alpha$ such that $\alpha=p\circ \gamma$.
>
> Call $\frac{\gamma(1)-\gamma(0)}{2\pi i}$ **the winding number of $\alpha$**.

Is it okay to define "winding number" in this way? That is, does this definition exactly mean the winding number?

Comment: What is your definition of *winding number*?

Comment: @Seirios I don't have one. This is the first time I'm studying somewhat related to that.

Comment: @Rubertos Sorry, I deleted my initial comment, realised that I hadn't read your question properly (my fault for trying to be clever before my morning coffee).

Comment: @BenjaminAlderson No problem and I deleted the comment :)

Comment: @Seirios and Rubertos: I understand the question to mean that ${\gamma (a) - \gamma (0) \over 2 \pi i}$ is the definition of the winding number of $\alpha$. Is it not?

Comment: @student Exactly, but now I prefer the definition here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186512/definition-of-winding-number-have-doubt-in-definition

Comment: See EuYu's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, yes. If  you have a closed curve $\alpha$, then from beginning to end it only differs by a phase $e^{2\pi i n}$. Using the exponential map as you have, you see that this gives you exactly the number of times that your curve has wound around the origin.