# Compute the winding number of $\alpha(z)=4z^4+2z^2+1$ and $\alpha(z)=6z^2+7z+2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, winding-number

The winding number of $\gamma$ about $0$ is given as: $w(\gamma, 0)=\frac{arg(\gamma(1))-arg(\gamma(0))}{2\pi}$

$\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ is a loop in $\mathbb{C}$ not passing through the origin (so $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$)

As $\gamma$ is a loop $arg(\gamma(1))-arg(\gamma(0))$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$

**Question 1:** Compute the winding number of the loop $\alpha(z)=4z^4+2z^2+1: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} -$ {$0$} about the origin $0$

**Question 2:** Compute the winding number of the polynomial loop $\alpha(z)=6z^2+7z+2: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} -$ {$0$} about the origin $0$

The only way I can think of doing these is to prove the loops are homotopic to a simple loop, such as $4z^4$ and $6z^2$ respectively . Is this the right idea?

Answer (score 1):

I will mainly give something that is sometimes underrepresented in lectures on complex analysis: **intuition**.

In itself, "phase unfolding", the name given when dealing with angles in a range larger than $2 \pi$, is rather puzzling.

It is why I give a graphical hint (see figure below) under the form of a "Western" analogy for the winding number (see figure) you are attached to the torture pole in $0$: how many circles do the indians around you (Hollywood image of course...)? The answer here is 4 times, which is the winding number. The unfolding of the curve is represented as a "lifting" (classical term) of the 2D curve into a 3D curve with ordinates the angle (range $[0,2\pi]$) as can be understood on the program I have given in the Appendix below (which, as well, computes the winding number).

The definition of the winding number you may have already met is:

$$\dfrac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C}\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\dfrac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{f(C)}\dfrac{1}{Z}dZ \ \ \ (1)$$

(where (C) is the unit circle, but could be any simple closed loop around the origin). See mathexchange question ([definition of winding number, have doubt in definition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186512)) for the details of computation.

Once again, what intuitive grasp on the fact that this integral (1) is connected to the winding number?

A reason is that a primitive of the function $f'(z)/f(z)$ is

$$log(f(z))=log(Z)= log(R e^{i \Theta})=log R +i \Theta$$

(I should say: having agreed about a starting reference for $\Theta$, because for example $log R +i(\Theta+2\pi)$ would be another candidate).

And $log(f(z))$ is there for counting $+2 \pi$ each time there is a crossing of its "cut" along the negative real axis, i.e., counting the number of turns around the origin; the argument of $log(f(z))$ proceeds by "$2 \pi$ jumps" each time the current point crosses the negative part of the $x$-axis.

[image]

**Appendix:** here is the Matlab program that has produced the figure:

```
clear all;close all;hold on;
t=0:0.01:2*pi;
z=exp(i*t);
Z=4*z.^4+2*z.^2+1;
view([-6,28]);
plot(real(Z),imag(Z),'color','b')
plot3(real(Z),imag(Z),t,'color','r')
plot3([0,0],[0,0],[0,2*pi],'color','k');

logdev=@(z)((16*z.^3+4*z)./(4*z.^4+2*z.^2+1));
windnbr=(1/(2*i*pi))*integral(logdev,1,1,'waypoints',[i,-1,-i])
%integration on the square [1,i,-1,-i,1] instead of the unit circle
```

Comment: Once more, an brave anonymous downvoter today (Jan 7 '22).